# VBA Excel how to hide modules

Tags: excel, vba, module

what I'm tryna to find out is how to hide modules when sb else is working with my vba code? I want one of my modules to be hidden...

Comment: What do you mean by ``when sb else is working with my vba code``? Did you try to set a password protection to your VBAProject?

Comment: You cannot. The VBE does not offer such functionality. You can only password protect the entire VBA project.

Comment: Oops, that is the answer I was searching for. Thank u